# How to make tail command end itself

Tags: terminal, filesystems, tail

In my app I use `tail -q -f -n +1 [file name]` to read current data of a file (dynamically growing file) and continue reading new chunks until the end. But that command never exits. It stays alive in the background.

How can I make it exit when appending to file is finished?

Comment: How would any monitoring process know that appending to the file is finished?

Comment: What @AndrewHenle wrote. Perhaps fiddling some timeout would help.

Comment: @ AndrewHenle I don't know. This is what I'm asking.

Comment: What is the command? Is it a script? Is it an exe? Do you have the source? I would have the source set up a flag with another process monitoring it and when set, kill the tail. Or have the process itself kill the tail. Or...

Comment: @Bib I know. I implemented the approach you say at first. The problem is my app (NodeJS) can't kill tail commands at all! I tried so may ways to kill them but didn't succeed. So I'm looking for a way that it can terminate itself.

Comment: @MC68020 I don't think tail itself accepts timeout. Does it? Then how would it be?

Comment: Perhaps the process owner of the tail is different from that trying to kill it, which would fail.

Comment: @Bib No the app itself runs it. It's NodeJS problem I think.

Comment: @jameshofer How do **you** know that the file is complete?

Comment: @AndrewHenle EOF or something maybe? I'm not Linux expert.

Comment: @jameshofer There would have to be an EOF somewhere in the file that it's reading. Even if `EOF` were somehow implemented, it would only stop reading the file when that appears. It wouldn't cause the process running the `tail` command to stop. What would it care?

Comment: "EOF or something maybe?" – Do you mean a literal string `EOF` your writing process deliberately prints to the file just before it finishes? Or do you mean the abstract end of the file? If the latter then be advised EOF is a condition. When there is no more data to read from a regular file, the reading process successfully gets 0 bytes and then it knows it's the end. `tail -f` is *designed* to ignore this and keep trying, otherwise it wouldn't wait for more data to come. So again: how do **you** know that the file is complete? Only with this information we may be able to automate the logic.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of `tail -f` is that it waits forever for new data to appear on its input file or stream (and `tail -F` can even auto-detected that an input file has been rotated, and re-open the filename).

If you want something fancier than that, you'll have to write it yourself.  If all you needed was to kill `tail` X seconds after it started, you could use a wrapper script or function to run `tail` via `timeout` from coreutils.

If you needed something more complex (e.g. exit on matching a particular pattern, or after X seconds without seeing any new text, or when some other program has exited / no longer appears in the system's process list), you could write your own version of `tail` with, for example, perl's [File::Tail](https://metacpan.org/release/File-Tail) module.   This module is great for, e.g., writing monitoring scripts that watch a log file and take certain actions when it sees certain patterns.

Other languages have similar capabilities (e.g. for Python, see [Get last n lines of a file, similar to tail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136168/get-last-n-lines-of-a-file-similar-to-tail)). You could probably even hack something up in bash but that would almost certainly be much more work for an inferior result.